# Passing parameters not working on specific function when Selenium IDE is open

Tags: javascript, selenium

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/Qh5Xk/4/

There is a prompt function that can be used to open custom pop-ups. You can tell it what function to call on a submit.

This currently works fine in IE7-10, FireFox and Chrome.

However, the second I try to do it with Selenium IDE open in Firefox, the callback function and prompt variables once passed into `prompt()` are always "undefined", the title is fine. I can alert them before the function call and the values are fine. If I alert them inside the function, only the first parameter has survived.

Annoyingly even with Selenium open on JSFiddle, the example I've given works, I've even used the same function and parameter names.

The only other thing of value I can find in the Console is:

```
Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead. @ chrome://selenium-ide/content/recorder.js:132
```

"Cannot access dead object" appears in the console sometimes (Line 702 of Seleniums editor.js)

```
// the line in question if anyone's interested.
this.log.debug("window.name=" + window.name + ", lastWindow.name=" + this.lastWindow.name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know why I didn't try this sooner.

`alert(prompt);` with the IDE open, returns `"function() { native code }"`. So I renamed the prompt function and it works fine.

`prompt()` is already a declared function. I have no idea why I haven't hit this problem sooner and why running Selenium seems break it.

Answer (score 0):

If Selenium also has a prompt() function it could be getting confused.